# Recursive function to filter out array of objects based on ID regardless of parent or children elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, reduce

I need to filter the below array of objects based on ID regardless of parent or child, if `_id` is found in the parent then remove that element and return rest, and if it is found in a child, then remove that child element and return rest.

```
const arrayToBeFiltered = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    assets: [
      {
        _id: "2",
      },
      {
        _id: "3",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: "4",
    assets: [
      {
        _id: "5",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

So, if I pass 3 then it should return:

```
[
  {
    _id: "1",
    assets: [
      {
        _id: "2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: "4",
    assets: [
      {
        _id: "5",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

And if I pass 4 then it should return:

```
[
  {
    _id: "1",
    assets: [
      {
        _id: "2",
      },
      {
        _id: "3",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: So what is holding you back?

Comment: Tried, but unable to append assets.

Comment: Check the answer I provided @Vipul Plz make sure to mark it as correct and give a upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try the below code for reference :

```js
const arrayToBeFiltered = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    assets: [
      {
        _id: "2",
      },
      {
        _id: "3",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: "4",
    assets: [
      {
        _id: "5",
      },
    ],
  },
];

function removeIdFromArray(array, idToRemove) {
  return array.filter((element) => {
    if (element._id === idToRemove) {
      return false;
    }

    if (element.assets) {
      element.assets = removeIdFromArray(element.assets, idToRemove);
    }

    return true;
  });
}



const newArray = removeIdFromArray(arrayToBeFiltered, "3");
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

Comment: I'm getting following error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: This is strange, I can execute the above code in the browser but not in my react application. Any advice?

Comment: Sample works fine.  Usually this happens when there is too many function calls. Can you please mark it as correct and upvote?

Comment: Found it, my mistake, rather than passing the param, I was directly using an array inside the method, which in recursion was causing the issue.